# PHP 7.2: How to create password protected zip using PHP 7.2

Tags: php, encryption, zip, password-protection, php-ziparchive

Can anyone suggest how can we create password protected zip in php 7.2

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

//now working in php 7.2"
$zip->setPassword($password);

//also this is not creating protected zip

$zip->setEncryptionName($filename, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256, $password);
```

Comment: You don't seem to open a file stream?

Comment: @Jonnix I did not mention it in code here , just highlighted code for password protection

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7.2, you should be able to use [`setEncryptionName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setencryptionname.php) to encrypt with a per-file password as the third argument, or, if [`setPassword`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php) was called previously, it can be omitted and the default password can be used.

Directly from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php#refsect1-ziparchive.setpassword-notes):

> As of PHP 7.2.0 and libzip 1.2.0 the password is used to decompress the archive, and is also the default password for ZipArchive::setEncryptionName() and ZipArchive::setEncryptionIndex(). Formerly, this function only set the password to be used to decompress the archive; it did not turn a non-password-protected ZipArchive into a password-protected ZipArchive.

The code below does both scenarios mentioned above. (Interestingly enough, my 7-Zip, when opening this file, appears to "remember" the last password entered so it won't let me try both until I re-open the file, but I think that is a bug in 7-Zip.)

```php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if (!$zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE)) {
    die('Could not create zip file');
}

// Set the shared/default password
$zip->setPassword('cheese');

// Add a file with the default password
$zip->addFromString('test-1.txt', 'this is file one');
$zip->setEncryptionName('test-1.txt', ZipArchive::EM_AES_256);

// Add a file with a custom password
$zip->addFromString('test-2.txt', 'this is file two');
$zip->setEncryptionName('test-2.txt', ZipArchive::EM_AES_256, 'custom password');
$zip->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in many different ways but it didn't work for me under linux using PHP 8.0. I have tried it on 2 different linux servers.
Libzip is installed and the recommended version is used.

At the end I used the other way that is recommended by many other developers:

```
<?php
$password    = 'get the password by some secure way';
$zipFileName = sprintf('compressed_file--%s-%s.zip', (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d'), mt_rand(0, 99999));
$zipFilePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . '/' . $zipFileName;
$contentFilePath = 'some_file_prepared_in_tmp_folder.xls';

system('cd /tmp; zip -P ' . $password . ' ' . $zipFilePath . ' ' . $contentFilePath);
?>
```